# reactor-http-epoll vs reactor-http-nio threads in Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I know Webflux uses just a few threads (typically equal to the number of CPU cores) to take a lot of requests. People typically see threads named `reactor-http-nio-?` like in [this post](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-avoid-blocking-in-reactive-java-757ec7024676)

However, I ran `jstack` on our Webflux app, I see these `reactor-http-epoll-?` threads instead:

```
"reactor-http-epoll-1" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=2983.38ms elapsed=36647.78s tid=0x00007f4efc8cb6d0 nid=0x47 runnable  [0x00007f4e98833000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:193)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:186)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:290)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:347)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.15/Thread.java:829)

"reactor-http-epoll-2" #29 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=6305.51ms elapsed=36647.78s tid=0x00007f4efdaa08e0 nid=0x48 runnable  [0x00007f4e98732000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
...

"reactor-http-epoll-3" #30 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1984.37ms elapsed=36647.78s tid=0x00007f4efddba9b0 nid=0x49 runnable  [0x00007f4e98631000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
...

"reactor-http-epoll-4" #31 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=2263.85ms elapsed=36647.78s tid=0x00007f4efd5dcd90 nid=0x4a runnable  [0x00007f4e98530000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
...
```

What are these threads, and how are they different from the `reactor-http-nio-?` threads?

Comment: epoll is a feature of linux you can read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll its basically polling multiple things at the same time.

Comment: NIO implements event loops using different OS functionality on different platforms.  On Linux it would most likely now use epoll, but it could use io_uring in future.  Before epoll it could have used select.  I suspect the naming just reflect that in the case of Linux where as on Windows I suspect it just says nio.

Comment: @AlwynSchoeman this explanation makes sense.